# hibernate creating table but that have no affect

Tags: mysql, hibernate, ejb, payara, java-ee-8

Can not create tables using hibernate. There is no error and log looks like it works but in database nothing changes. I'm using java, hibernate and mysql 8. Dialect which i used is: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect. Running on payara5 server.

My log:

```
2020-03-14T19:24:24.884+0100|INFO: GUI deployment: uploadToTempfile
2020-03-14T19:24:24.885+0100|INFO: uploadFileName=LoginCreatorImpl.war
2020-03-14T19:24:24.887+0100|INFO: ================== availabilityEnabled  skipped 
2020-03-14T19:24:26.624+0100|INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: test
    ...]
2020-03-14T19:24:26.746+0100|INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}
2020-03-14T19:24:26.749+0100|INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-03-14T19:24:26.888+0100|INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
2020-03-14T19:24:27.104+0100|INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2020-03-14T19:24:27.444+0100|INFO: HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
2020-03-14T19:24:28.179+0100|INFO: Hibernate: 

    drop table if exists NowaEncja
2020-03-14T19:24:28.187+0100|INFO: Hibernate: 

    create table NowaEncja (
       id bigint not null auto_increment,
        test varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
2020-03-14T19:24:28.191+0100|INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@a061b4a'
2020-03-14T19:24:28.369+0100|INFO: Portable JNDI names for EJB TestBean: [java:global/LoginCreatorImpl/TestBean!eu.pstdio.LoginCreatorImpl.business.dao.TestBean, java:global/LoginCreatorImpl/TestBean]
2020-03-14T19:24:28.663+0100|INFO: Clustered CDI Event bus initialized
2020-03-14T19:24:28.727+0100|INFO: Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        NowaEncja
        (test) 
    values
        (?)
2020-03-14T19:24:28.760+0100|INFO: Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01 for context '/LoginCreator'
2020-03-14T19:24:28.793+0100|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.payara-p3 for context '/LoginCreator'
2020-03-14T19:24:29.029+0100|INFO: Loading application [LoginCreatorImpl] at [/LoginCreator]
2020-03-14T19:24:29.175+0100|INFO: LoginCreatorImpl was successfully deployed in 4 205 milliseconds.
```

Comment: You are using the h2 datatase: `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` looks like a problem in your configuration

Comment: I added dialect to my persistence.xml org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect. Still not working but i have changes in my log. Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found place where problem exists. Because of some reasone hibernate ingoring my sql server credentials. I fixed this with setting `jta-data-source` but still i dont know why it not want work with credentials set in persistence.xml.